# Changing Date/Time in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have Date/Time string in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
2016-10-13 02:33:40
```

And I need to cut out the year/month/day completely, and convert the time to minutes. So that time/date above needs to be converted into just:

```
153
```

^^2 hours and 33 minutes = 153 minutes

I am basically trying to sift the data by the amount of time in between each entry and converting it all to minutes (since the amount of time that passes will not go past a day per session) seemed to make the most sense to me. But, I am open to any other suggestions!

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

lets say the date and time is in a column called DateTime.

```
df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"])
df["Minutes"] = 60*df["Datetime"].dt.hour +df["Datetime"].dt.minute
```

There once the datetime column is in the right format, you can access a lot of properties. See here for more https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a ton. Sorry, new to pandas and wasn't having any luck searching through forums.